# Crypto RSA in Python

Tags: python, public-key-encryption

I am checking a code written in Python which is used to generate an RSA public private key pair.

It generates the keypair however, at the end of the code it runs ssh-keygen again. I am not sure why that is done. Since, RSA.generate() will itself generate the keypair that we export into two separate files. Why is there a need to run ssh-keygen again?

Here are few lines from the code:

```
keypair = RSA.generate(1024, randfunc)

with open("pub", "w") as pubfile, open("id_rsa", "w") as privfile:
    privfile.write(keypair.exportKey())
    pubfile.write(keypair.publickey().exportKey())

system("ssh-keygen -m PKCS8 -i -f pub > id_rsa.pub && rm pub")
```

the file **pub** will store the public key and **id_rsa** will store the private key from the keypair generated by RSA.generate() function.

Now, why is it running the ssh-keygen command at the end?

Also, it does not take any input file for the -i parameter and -f parameter takes the name pub which was the public key already generated.

After executing the code I get two files, id_rsa and id_rsa.pub

id_rsa is the private key generated using RSA.generate() but id_rsa.pub stores the result of ssh-keygen command.

I need some help to understand the reason for invoking ssh-keygen at the end of the script and also the parameters passed to ssh-keygen. -i should be passed some value and also -f should have output filename and not input.

**Note:** I read that this is done to convert the public key from OpenSSL format to OpenSSH format using ssh-keygen so that it starts with ssh-rsa instead of BEGIN PUBLIC KEY.

Does that mean the format of corresponding private key should also be changed?

Since it starts with,

BEGIN PRIVATE KEY

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in the fact that ssh-keygen is run to convert the generated PEM Format Public Key into a OpenSSH Format Public Key.
There's no really good way to do this in Python as far as I know.

The OpenSSH format only exists for a Public Key.
So, no, you do not need to convert the Private Key if it begins with
`-------- BEGIN PRIVATE KEY ---------` or `-------- BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY ---------`