# How to use public/private keys for short data without a symmetric cipher

Tags: javascript, python, c, openssl, public-key-encryption

I'd like to encrypt and decrypt data with private and public keys, respectively.

The data is between 1 and 32 bytes.

I do not want to use a symmetric cipher for the data - I want to use the keys on the data directly.  (This is not normally done for performance reasons, but my data is very small.)

Is this possible and Where should I start?

Comment: Technically, public and private keys use asymmetric encryption/decryption, not symmetric, so, yes, it is possible. As for how to do it, that depends on what cipher you use. You have a lot of choices, like RSA, DSA, etc..

Comment: DES, Blowfish and Caeser are all symmetric.

Comment: Oh, right. Sorry, I'm not brushed up on my cipher knowledge. It's all ciphertext to me haha. Edited with pretty much the only other asymmetric one I know.

Comment: Yes it is possible. RSA, for example, can be used to encrypt data blocks up to the size of the modulus (less 11 bytes if you're using padding). Since you'd be crazy to not use at least a 1024 key, and rec 2048 or larger, that gives you 117 (or 245+) bytes of data to pack in a single cipher block, which is more than enough for what you need.

Comment: The reasons this is not normally done have little to do with performance - encrypting predictable and/or small blocks of data with an asymmetric algorithm like RSA is often **insecure**. Unless you are absolutely certain of what you're doing, use a symmetric cipher and encrypt the (random) key with the asymmetric scheme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'd like to encrypt and decrypt data with private and public keys

Pretty much anyone who's worked with crypto will tell you that you write crypto at your own risk.  Use the standard libraries, they're made with all the things that (if you are not aware of these techniques) leave your traffic unsecured.

That said, here's some Python libraries (but you can get this in most languages from PHP to Java or whatever floats your boat):

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycrypto

https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/

[Crypto RSA in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17496619/crypto-rsa-in-python)

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyECC

You'll see pycrypto because it's popular if you're looking to use RSA.  Another package is PyECC which includes functionality for elliptic curve crypto.  This is important if you're looking to reduce your key size or have less resources to devote to crypto, usually in mobile systems or something small.  The [difference in key sizes (link)](http://www.codeguru.com/images/article/12799/ECCSecurity2.gif) can get ridiculous as the keys grow (for increased security)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe keyczar is what you're looking for:
http://www.keyczar.org/